# How do i get my selected id in dropdown angular?

Tags: angular

How do I get my selected id from dropdown. I tried to do this, but its only displaying first value id.is there any wrong in my ts or HTML. Appreciate your help, thank you.
Html:

```html
     <select name="" [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel"  id="syncPolicy" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let data of ClusterIdDetails" [value]="data.clusterId">{{ data.clusterName }}</option>
     </select>
```

ts

```js
     getClusterInfo() {
         this.ProjectClusterService.getPassClusterData().subscribe(res => {
              this.ClusterIdDetails = res['1tool-gitlab-pipeline']
              this.selectedLevel = this.ClusterIdDetails[0].clusterId
              console.log(this.selectedLevel,"cluster")
         });
     }
```

Comment: When you are using "ngModel" like in your code it's automatically set the clusterId to selectedLevel. This is the simple term of 2 way binding. Why you do it again in ts file?

Comment: I have to send that selected id to the backend, That's y I am trying to store that selected id in some variable, So that I can send it to the backend

Comment: It's happen when you use "ngModel". chech [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/great-cartwright-07mcp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Yes @Dananjaya, I noted your point and tried it, removed those extra lines in ts. it worked. thank you. your comment helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing the below

```js
   this.selectedLevel = this.ClusterIdDetails[0].clusterId
```

It will always get the first ID.

Please check how are you getting the selected `clusterId`

Comment: Thank you for your response, Could you please tell me how can i get every selected id instead of first Id

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, in the select dropdown first item will be selected as default due to below line:

```
this.selectedLevel = this.ClusterIdDetails[0].clusterId
```

Now if you want to get the clusterId of selected option then you can bind `ngModelChange` event with `<select>` box.

Try below code:

```
<select name="" [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel" (ngModelChange)="handleOptionChange()"  id="syncPolicy" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let data of ClusterIdDetails" [value]="data.clusterId">{{ data.clusterName }}</option>
     </select>
```

TS

```
handleOptionChange() {
    console.log(this.selectedLevel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond, But i would like to store selected id in some variable so that i can send that selected id to the backend, that's my main requirement.

Comment: Great. Please give a vote by just pressing up arrow on my reply. ;)

Comment: Hello @Suneeth Bansal, sorry for the late reply. Its actually worked without adding ngModelChange event. But your answer also helped me too. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers, I have missed adding line in post call and trying to add extra variable. As per above suggestions, I have removed extra lines in my get call(ts file).added this.selectedLevel in post call. it worked. Thank you.

final html:

```
<select name="" [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel"   id="syncPolicy" class="form-control">
                                <option *ngFor="let data of ClusterIdDetails" [value]="data.clusterId">{{ data.clusterName }}</option>
                                
                            </select>
```

final ts.

```
getClusterInfo() {
   
  this.ProjectClusterService.getPassClusterData().subscribe(res => {
      this.ClusterIdDetails = res['1tool-gitlab-pipeline']
    
    })
```

my post call
sendclusteridApi() {

```
const data = {
  "clusterData": [
    this.selectedLevel
  ],
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on how you exactly solved the issue? Instead of describing the solution, you could show it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yeah Sure, Sorry about it, I didn't add any new lines, I have just removed extra code in ts file. I added my final code, and it worked for me. Hope it helps. Thank you.